# Redirect url query string on multiple pages

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm trying to accomplish rewrite and redirect URL query string as folder.

My rewrite/redirect is as per the below:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?folder/sub-folder-with-get-param-(.*?)/?$ /folder.php?key=$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /folder\.php\?key=([^\&\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^/?folder\.php$ /folder/sub-folder-with-get-param-%1? [L,R=301]
```

The above works but once I get to the directed page and do a secondary search the URL returns:

```
/folder/folder?key=value
```

Which returns a 500 internal server error.

How would I go about in fixing this - would I need to do a secondary redirect? sorry if this is a stupid question I just find redirects hard to get my head around.

Thanks

Comment: `I get to the directed page and do a secondary search`: Can you run this Chrome dev tool with **caching disabled** and check in Network tab what are 301/302 redirect URLs you get

Comment: @anubhava I'm getting one 301: Request URL: folder/folder.php?key=value and a 500 error becaue folder/folder.php?key=value should be folder.php?key=value ?

Comment: Do you have more rules in this htaccess? Where is this located?

Comment: Yes i have more rules but I've put these at the top so there shouldn't be any conflicts. Could this be due to having the form on the second page having the action as "action='folder.php' "? so it's appending to the rewriten rule?

Comment: Try adding this just below `<head>` tag of your page's HTML: `<base href="/" />`